# Matching combination closest to end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match the combination of any pronouns plus any adverbs that's closest to the end of the string. So in the example below, I'm trying to get it to match the words "she is", since that is closest to the end of the string. How would I do that?

```
$pronounsMatch = "i|me|my|you|your|it|he|she|her|his|us|our|they|their|them|this|these|that|those|the|yourself|myself";
$adverbsMatch = "may|do|dont|does|doesnt|did|didnt|am|is|isnt|was|wasnt|were|werent|are|arent|can|cant|could|couldnt|will|wont|would|wouldnt|should|shouldnt|have|havent|has|hasnt|had|hadnt";
$temp = "i am so into food and he is here but she is not";
preg_match("~\b($pronounsMatch) ($adverbsMatch)\b(.+)? ([a-z]+)$~", $temp, $match);

print_r($match);

Array ( [0] => i am so into food and he is here but she is not [1] => i [2] => am [3] => so into food and he is here but she is [4] => not )
```

Right now it's matching the combination closest to the start of the string, which is "i am". How would I fix this?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/7X14aC

Comment: Start your pattern with a greedy quantifier: `.*` (eventually use the s modifier if you have newlines in the string.). This way, the search *starts from the end of the string* since the pattern uses the backtracking mechanism to find `\b($pronounsMatch) ($adverbsMatch)\b(.+)? ([a-z]+)$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes! This works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: `(?(DEFINE)
  (?<pronoun>i|me|my|you|your|it|he|she|her|his|us|our|they|their|them|this|these|that|those|the|yourself|myself)
  (?<adverb>may|do|dont|does|doesnt|did|didnt|am|is|isnt|was|wasnt|were|werent|are|arent|can|cant|could|couldnt|will|wont|would|wouldnt|should|shouldnt|have|havent|has|hasnt|had|hadnt)
)
\b(?&pronoun)\s(?&adverb)\s(\w+)`? [See it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/8GsJB5/1)

Comment: You can eventually speed up the search if you add `(?=[imyhsuot])` *(first letter of each item of the first alternation)* after the word boundary *(need to be tested)*.

Comment: Updated the code since my last comment: https://regex101.com/r/8GsJB5/3

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Wouldn't an anti-greedy `.*` at the end do the same? I'm not sure if PHP's regex engine can do it, but I'm thinking of Python's `.*?`, which would match as little characters as possible. I'd use it as `.*?$`, of course.

Comment: Your list of adverbs is actually a list of verbs.

Comment: @Rightleg: unfortunately not, because the regex engine reads the string from the left to the right and returns the leftmost occurrence. If you write something like `a.*?z` for the string "a___a---z___z" you will obtain "a___a---z" and not "a---z". The reluctant quantifier can't change the fact that the first `a` is the leftmost and is found first. The reluctant quantifier in this example will only avoid a match until the last z, but it can't change the start of a match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh, so that's why!Thank you very much for the explanation.